# PowerShell Script Permission export shows ' System.Object'

Tags: powershell

> Scipt is outputting some permissions as "system.object[]" and cant
> seem to work it out

```
$FolderPath = dir -Directory -Path "\\fs1\Shared" -Recurse -Force
    $Report = @()
    Foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
        $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
        foreach ($Access in $acl.Access)
            {
                $Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder.FullName;'AD
    Group or
    User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
                $Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
            }
    }
    $Report | Export-Csv -path "C:\data\FolderPermissions.csv"
```

Comment: Join these items that are arrays with a delimiter character of your choice. Something like: `$Permissions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Permissions -Value ($PermissionLevels -join '; ')`. BTW. You're creating the objects 'old-school'. The code would improve if you create them using `[PsCustomObject]@{...}` and inside the curly brackets just state your properties and values each on a new line like `Permissions = $PermissionLevels -join '; '` etc.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you can improve the readability of the code by building your objects using `[PsCustomObject]`.

Some properties will contain arrays you need to join with a separator character. If you don't, they will show up in the report as 'System.Object[]'

Also, it is extremely time and memory consuming to add items to an array with `+=`.
In PowerShell there is a much better way of doing this by capturing the output in a variable like this:

```
$PermissionCollection = foreach($RoleAssignment in $Object.RoleAssignments) { 
    #Get the Permission Levels assigned and Member
    #Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $RoleAssignment -Property RoleDefinitionBindings, Member

    #Get the Principal Type: User, SP Group, AD Group
    $PermissionType = $RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType

    #Get the Permission Levels assigned
    $PermissionLevels = $RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings | Select -ExpandProperty Name

    #Remove Limited Access
    #$PermissionLevels = ($PermissionLevels | Where { $_ -ne "Limited Access"}) -join ","

    #Leave Principals with no Permissions
    If($PermissionLevels.Length -eq 0) {Continue}

    # create an object to output with the common properties already filled in
    $obj = [PsCustomObject]@{
        Object               = $ObjectType
        Title                = $ObjectTitle
        URL                  = $ObjectURL
        HasUniquePermissions = $HasUniquePermissions
        Users                = $null   # fill this in later
        Type                 = $PermissionType
        Permissions          = $PermissionLevels -join ', '
        GrantedThrough       = $null   # fill this in later
    }

    #Get SharePoint group members
    If($PermissionType -eq "SharePointGroup") {
        #Get Group Members
        $GroupMembers = Get-PnPGroupMembers -Identity $RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName
             
        #Leave Empty Groups
        If($GroupMembers.count -eq 0){Continue}

        $obj.Users = ($GroupMembers | Select -ExpandProperty Title) -join ","
        $obj.GrantedThrough = "SharePoint Group: $($RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName)"
    }
    Else {
        $obj.Users = ($RoleAssignment.Member.Title) -join ","
        $obj.GrantedThrough = "Direct Permissions"
    }

    # now simply output the $obj so it gets collected in variable $PermissionCollection
    $obj
}
#Export Permissions to excel File
# $PermissionCollection | Export-CSV $ReportFile -NoTypeInformation -Append
$PermissionCollection | export-excel $ReportFile -Append
```

There may be more properties that contain arrays you need to join, This is just an example.